# Resharper suggesting to make overloaded method private

Tags: c#, resharper

I have methods similar to below:

```
public string Method(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Called Method(string s)");
    return s;
}

public string Method(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Called Method(object o)");
    return Method(o == null ? null : o.ToString());
}
```

Resharper says on the first method

> Method 'Method' can be made private

I believe this is incorrect because if I call:

```
Method(new SomeClass())
```

Then the output is

> Called Method(object o)
>    Called Method(string s)

and if I call

```
Method("some string")
```

the output is

> Called Method(string s)

So why is Resharper suggesting this seemingly incorrect refactoring?

Comment: resharper makes suggestions depending on your existing code, so if you have no usages of `Method(string s)` outside from the declaring class you'll get such suggestion

Comment: You get into a loop when calling Method(object o) with null. I would suggest you to write something like 'return o == null ? string.Empty : Method(o.ToString());'.

Comment: @wonko79 Actually the compiler chooses the most specific overload for the input. In the case of `null` the compiler will choose the `string` overload over the `object` overload as `string` can be `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ReSharper** is smart enough to determine where a particular class member is actually being used. If it isn’t used outside the type it’s in (not even in derived types), it will offer to mark the member as `private`. If the member is used in derived classes too, it will offer to mark it as `protected`.

[Source](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Member+can+be+made+private+%28protected%29)